# fabric-code that make the client chat automatically when connecting to the server

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am a fabric-client mod user. I'm not a developer. However, it is very annoying to enter the same command every time I connect to the server. So I want to make my own mod that makes me type command (like "/spawn") or chat (like "hello") when I connect to the server. I have basic knowledge of java, but I don't have the ability to handle fabric or packets. what code is the simplest and best?

code that the client sends messages to the server automatically when connected to the server